# <C-x><C-o> "Pattern not found" even with a Ctags file (C/C++)

Tags: autocompletion, tags, ctags

`<C-x><C-o>` returns `Pattern not found` in C/C++ files even with a ctags file.

- It used to work and I haven't made any configuration/plugin changes that I know of
- Starting vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE` and manually setting `omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete` results in the same problem (as does `vim --clean`), so it doesn't seem to be caused by my vim config
- Python and HTML omnicomplete still works, so the problem seems to be with the tags file
- `<C-]>` and `<C-x><C-]>` still work and complain when the tags file is removed, so the tags file seems to be fine??
- I'm using Gutentags with Universal-Ctags in Vim 8.2 to automatically generate the tags file (tried a stock Neovim config as well and *still* the same error)

Any ideas what the problem could be or how I could go about debugging it?

Comment: `it doesn't seem to be caused by my vim config` -u NONE results in skipping all plugins and entering compatible mode. No way your plugin-based completion can work under these circumstances. So your test is totally worthless.

Comment: Omnicomplete is a builtin vim feature. Running without vimrc and plugins was to rule those out as causes but thanks for being unnecessarily aggressive I guess?

Comment: @hopibel you could try the --clean flag; also, ctrl-x ctrl-] should complete tags specifically. You may want to see https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Same result with --clean, unfortunately. And ctrl-x ctrl-] still works for some reason. For whatever bizarre reason, the only thing that doesn't work is ctrl-x ctrl-o with a tags file.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but since it is getting bumped without an answer, I will provide an explanation anyway.

The reason `<C-x><C-o>` (omni-completion) returns "Pattern not found" can be found in the documentation:

```
CTRL-X CTRL-O           Guess what kind of item is in front of the cursor and
                        find the first match for it
```

The important word here is **Guess**. It cannot guess if you haven't typed at least a single letter, which I suspect that's what OP was trying to do.

[image]

but it definitely works using a prefix (in this case, the letter "f")

[image]

Most other completion functions work by **searching**, even though the description might lead you to believe that it shouldn't work either. For example,

```
CTRL-X CTRL-]           Search for the first tag that starts with the same
                        characters as before the cursor.
```

Contrary to the most complex `omni-complete` (see :h complete-functions) which requires a prefix, this type of autocompletion (tag completion) defaults to "show everything" as if nothing was filtered.

[image]

However, this doesn't explain why other filetypes seemed to work. As far as I know, other filetypes should work in exactly the same way, unless custom functions are set for the `omnifunc` option.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just gave up and installed the clang-complete plugin, which just worked without any fuss. I get the feeling omni-complete may not do what I think it does. The documentation suggests it should be able to complete struct member names but I simply wasn't able to get it to do so.